# Setting webcam properties

Tags: c#, webcam

I am writing a C# `Windows Form` application which communicates with a webcam.

However, I want to tune webcam properties inside a button `click` function. Examples of those properties are `brightness`, `saturation` and `sharpness`.

I have found `IAMVideoProcAmp::Set` which might aid me with this. However, I don't quite understand how to implement this.
Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

What you'll need to do is wrap calls to certain APIs (whether it's Windows, DirectX, etc) which is easier said than done when it comes to C#.

Luckily this problem has been solved numerous times (as you can see by number of webcam questions here) - and you can find one good approach in the following article:
[Versatile WebCam C# library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library)

Answer (score 0):

Check out "[How to change contrast and saturation programmatically?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/de6cc000-93b9-457d-85c2-97589fde38c1/)"